# googles ArrayListMultimap

Tags: java, guava

I am iterating the elements of an `ArrayListMultimap` like this:

```
for(MyKey key : multimap.keySet()) {
    List<MyValue> values = multimap.get(key);
    // multimap.containsKey(key) returns false
    for(MyValue val : values) {
        // sometimes the list is empty
    }
}
```

but when tring to retrieve the value for a key I get an empty list. Also `multimap.containsKey(key)` returns false.
When I try to iterate using `entries()`, the key and the values are found.

I am using `guava-14.0.1.jar`, but I tried older versions and I get the same behaviour.
Also, sometimes there are nulls as values and I have overwitten the equals and hash methods for MyKey and MyValue.

Any idea what could cause this? I am sure it's not the `ArrayListMultimap` implementation.

Comment: I am not sure if you have overridden your equals and hashCode methods. Have you done that?

Comment: yes, I have overwitten the equals and hashCode methods and I have tested them a bit, I have found no problem there. I have also tried to use the 'default' equals and hashCode methods but the problem remains.

Comment: @Sap also, it's very strange, the problem doesn't occur very often, when I just do some normal tests, everything works fine.

Comment: Could we _see_ the implementations of `hashCode` and `equals`?

Comment: FYI, _if_ you just want to iterate over all the values in your multimap, using `multimap.values()` is preferable to a nested loop like that. But I suspect that your `equals` method is in some way violating the requirement that an object always be equal to itself.

Comment: Is `MyKey` actually immutable? If a key is changed after it has been used in the `Multimap` (or a `HashMap`, for that matters), and the change effects `hashCode()` and `equals()`, you won't be able to find the associated values anymore.

Comment: @FrankPavageau: neither MyKey nor MyValue are mutable. Didn't think about that. I will try to remove all the items and add them again to the Multimap to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @FrankPavageau: Yes, that was the problem. Some of the keys and values would change and their hashcode changed as well. If you make an answer out of your comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `MyKey` actually immutable?

If a key is changed after it has been used in the `Multimap` (or a `HashMap`, for that matters), and the change effects `hashCode()` and `equals()`, you won't be able to find the associated values anymore: the modified hashcode means the lookup does not happen in the bucket where the values were stored.